# How do I add a definition for a React Component imported from a library

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, flowtype

I use `material-ui` in my React project. I am trying to introduce Flow to the mix.

An example:

```
import Paper from 'material-ui/Paper';

type Props = {
  ruleName: string,
  rules: Object[],
  actions: string[],
  allowSubmit: boolean,
  onSubmit: ?Function,
}

const NotifyRule = (props: Props) => (
  <Paper style={{ padding: 10, width: '100%' }}>
      ....
  </Paper>
);
```

I tried to write definitions for material-ui as

```
declare module 'material-ui' {
  declare type Paper = any;
  declare var exports: 'material-ui';
}
```

This does not work. I get a failure:

`import Paper from 'material-ui/Paper';
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ material-ui/Paper. Required module not found`

Any pointers on solving this would be really helpful.

Comment: did you specify [libs] section in you .flowconfig?

Comment: yes, I believe I have the right libs.

Comment: Could you post more code? Anything that is related to this

Answer (score 3):

You have to declare submodules separately to make flow recognize it:

```
declare module 'material-ui/Paper' {
   declare var exports: any;
}

declare module 'material-ui' {
   // Note: That export value looks weird to me, but whatever
   declare var exports: 'material-ui';
}
```

We did something similar with redux-saga in the `flow-typed` repository... maybe you get some inspiration there :-)

https://github.com/flowtype/flow-typed/blob/master/definitions/npm/redux-saga_v0.11.x/flow_%3E%3Dv0.28.x/redux-saga_v0.11.x.js